# How to use Jquery to add click function for run time added image?

Tags: jquery, html

i have a HTML table markup which generated on browser when user click. here is the Code

```
$('#selectedtable > tbody:first').append(
    '<tr > ' +
        '<td>Chair</td>' +
        '<td><img src="/Content/images/showinfo.png" title="Show Info"></td>' +
    '</tr>'
    );
```

So my question is that possible to add click event for the above generated image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either add the onclick handler just after you added your image to the dom, with

```
$("#my-image").click(function() {
     alert("I've been clicked");
});
```

(For an image with an id `my-image`)

Or you can set a handler that will be applied to all future added elements:

```
$(document).on("click", ".image-class", function() {
     alert("I've been clicked");
});
```

(For images with classes `.image-class`)

Comment: Thanks. i prefer the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the element with ID #selectedtable exists when the page loads, use `.on()`'s event delegation syntax:

```
$('#selectedtable').on('click', 'img', function(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets added to the DOM, therefore you should be able to select it like you would select any DOM element and add whatever event handlers you want.